# Need .js and HTML example for displaying .STL 3D objects in a web page

Tags: 3d, webgl, three.js

Can anybody produce a clean "for dummies" example of HTML for using [STLLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js) to display ASCII (not binary) .stl object files in a web page? Result should let users manipulate object in current HTML5 browsers and with no fancy visuals beyond a grayscale object surface and background.

STLLoader.js might need the help of three.js or three.min.js but I wouldn't know. STLLoader.js contains below usage example but did not include an HTML wrapper.

**Usage example inside** [STLLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js)

```
     /** 
     * Usage:
     *  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
     *  loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
     *
     *      var geometry = event.content;
     *      scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry ) );
     *
     *  } );
     *  loader.load( './models/stl/slotted_disk.stl' );
     */
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The three.js examples are a good source:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html

Here is the basic pattern to follow:

```js
const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

loader.load( 'slotted_disk.stl', function ( geometry ) {

    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533 } );

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

three.js r161

Comment: That webgl_loader_stl.html page fails in current Chrome and Firefox when I carefully replicate its .js and .stl files onto my web server. Page was mostly black with some info at top. Other 3D .js pages on the web work when transplanted into my test environment but I don't know enough to declare a glitch in [webgl_loader_stl.html](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html).

Comment: I simplified the example for you. You can't get much simpler than this. If you are having other issues, please make a new post and provide a live link if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to get the `stl` model rendered in `IE(9)`?? It is not working and m getting this error `SCRIPT5009: 'DataView' is undefined 
STLLoader.js, line 82 character 3
`

Comment: @Uttara - You need to make a new post.